# c++ inherit class template with this class as the type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want my class template A to be able to have a member, that is only defined in B, while B inherits A.

Here is the code that would theoretically work, but doesn't compile.

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
public:
    typename T::member mSomething;
};

class B : public A< B >
{
public:
    struct member
    {
        int val;
    };
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    B* b = new B;
    A<B>* a = b;

    b->mSomething.val = 5;

    if( a->mSomething.val == 5 )
    {
        std::cout << "doing good";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile on MSVCP 2010 with the error" 'member' : is not a member of 'B' "

How could I get around this?

Comment: Full compilation and errors [here](http://ideone.com/dzM4pJ)

Comment: In short and simple words, you can't. Base classes must be fully defined at the moment when the inheriting class starts being compiled. If your "Foo" wants to derive from "Bar", then "Bar" must be completely fully known. Therefore you can't have Bar defined inside Foo, because then the Bar would be fully parsed/compiled only somewhere in the middle of Foo's compilation, not strictly before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRTP base classes can't access types defined in the derived class. When `A<B>` is instantiated, `B` is an incomplete type and has no members, so you can't access the contents.

You must define the type outside `B`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, this is the solution that I ended up using:

```
// Base class in file 1
template< typename T, typename TT >
struct A
{
    TT foo;
};

// derived in file 2, one class for the member outside the definition
// and one main class.
struct C
{
    int val;
};

struct B : public A< B, C >
{

};

// Usage from wherever you please.
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    B* b = new B;
    A<B, C>* a = b;

    b->foo.val = 5;

    if( a->foo.val == 5 )
    {
        std::cout << "doing good";
    }

    return 0;
}
```